# Add buttons in a loop dynamically in HBox which is already present in javafx UI

Tags: user-interface, button, javafx

I am fetching the count of the rows from the db table on click of one button and depending upon the count ,I am adding the buttons in HBOX which is already present in the UI. That loop is running fine but My problem here is only one button with the last entry in the loop is being added to the ui .

On click of the button  Called Function is:

```
  @FXML
 public void goToProjectUpdateScreen(ActionEvent event) {

         Session session = NewHibernateUtil.opensession();
        session.beginTransaction();

       Query queryResult = session.createQuery("from Project where RegistrationId= 3");

  java.util.List allUsers;
  allUsers = queryResult.list();
  for (int i = 0; i < allUsers.size(); i++) {
             try {
                 Project project = (Project) allUsers.get(i);
                 Button button = new Button();
                 button.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent t) ->
        {
            System.out.println(button.getId());

        });
                 button.setText(project.getProjectname());
                 button.setId(Integer.toString(project.getProjectid()));

   showProjectUpdateDialog(button,project.getProjectname());

           } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(NewProjectScreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

  }



        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
   public void showProjectUpdateDialog(Button button,String buttonname) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ProjectUpdateScreen.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        ProjectUpdateScreenController controller = fxmlLoader.<ProjectUpdateScreenController>getController();
        controller.setButton(button,buttonname);
        fxmlLoader.setController(button);
        MainController.parentWindow.getScene().setRoot(root);
    }
```

SetButton Function in Project Update Screen:

```
 @FXML
      public HBox projectlist;

    public  void setButton(Button button ,String buttonname) {

    projectlist.setSpacing(10);

projectlist.getChildren().add(button);


    }
```

Can anyone explain me about this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load the fxml only once. Currently you load it every time you add a button and set it as root, so the last one is the remaining one.